# MooTools Fx.Slide duration

Tags: javascript, mootools

I use `MooTools Fx.Slide` to open / close different containers on the same page.
Some containers hold only **little text**, others **very long text**.

When I set the `duration` to, say, `500`...

```
var thisSlider = 
    new Fx.Slide(item.getElement('.main'), 
    {duration: 500}
);
```

The small container opens slowly, the big one is rushing up and down very fast...

see http://jsfiddle.net/6H9f5/1/

**How can I have the containers open at the same *"average speed"*?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a option, more of a hack. Not sure it qualifies as an answer :)

```
    var itemMain = item.getElement('.main');
    var thisHeight = itemMain.getSize().y;
    var speed = 500 + (thisHeight * 3);
    console.log(speed); // to check the values proportion
    var thisSlider = new Fx.Slide(itemMain,{
        duration: speed
    });
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6H9f5/4/)